# Displaying images on hovering over points in d3.js scatter plot

Tags: image, d3.js, scatter-plot

I haven't used d3.js before and am attempting to create a scatterplot where hovering over the points displays the image itself (scaled down to a smaller size).

I have looked at some tutorials where text can be displayed when the mouse pointer hovers over the points. For example, I have looked at the following links: [1](http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e) and [2](https://bl.ocks.org/floofydugong/9c94ab01d8c3ed8ea3821d4a7e119b07). I would like to do something similar, but display the image itself when I hover over the point.

I am also not sure about replicating those links in a local folder. Consider the first link [1](http://bl.ocks.org/peterssonjonas/4a0e7cb8d23231243e0e), I created an index.html, serial.csv and scatter.css files locally and copied the given code. When I open index.html in a browser however, I see a blank screen with a single 'xAxis' button. The index.html file seems to use a scatter.js file that is not present in that link. Not sure about where I can get it from. My intent was to replace the text with an image tag instead.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend watching a video on how to make the scatterplots with d3, especially since you're not familiar with it. I found this video helpful to make the scatterplot:

https://vizhub.com/curran/9247d4d42df74185980f7b1f7504dcc5

Then, to make the hover effect with the image, you will need to use a **Tooltip**. You will have to attach it to all the circles which make up your scatterplot, and you would place your image as the attribute to 'background-image'. An example of code for this would be:

```
let svg = d3.select('svg');

let tooltip = d3
    .select("body")
    .append("div")
       .attr("id", "tooltip")

svg.selectAll('circle')
    // Create scatterplot points from dataset
    .data(dataset)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
        .attr('x', 'x-coord') // Location of circle on x-axis
        .attr('y', "y-coord") 
        .style('fill','#4aa89c')

        // Tooltip styling when mouse hovers over
        .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
            d3.select(this).style("fill", "a8eddf");
            tooltip.attr("id", "tooltip")
            tooltip.style("fill", "#a8eddf")
            tooltip.attr("data-date", d[0])
            tooltip.style('background-image','url("image-url")')
            tooltip.style('background-size','cover')
            tooltip.style('opacity', 1)             
         })

        // Tooltip styling when mouse is off the point
        .on("mouseout", function () {
            d3.select(this)
                .transition()
                .duration(400)
                .style("fill", "#4aa89c");
            tooltip.style("opacity", 0);
        })
```